# Combining Time Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, time

I have Shift ID, start time and end time columns but the shift is broken up into multiple rows and repeats the same ID. So how would I combine the fragmented shift by taking the first start time and the last end time into one row? I started but I don't know what comes after since I'm just beginning to dabble in code. I have the two pieces of bread but have no idea what the meat should be.

```
Sub Combine()

LR1 = Columns(1).Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LC1 = Rows(1).Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

For x = 1 To LR1

       If Cells(x,2).value    

End Sub
```

How do I indicate a change in cell value then combine the rows based on the first start time and end last time? I know I've barely written anything but I didn't envision this could to be long.

```
ShiftID:     StartTime:   EndTime:    Employee:
123456       6:45pm       7:00pm     Garcia Mendez
123456       7:00pm       9:30pm     Garcia Mendez
123456       9:30pm       2:45am     Garcia Mendez
654321       10:00am      12:00pm    Garcia Mendez
654321       12:00pm      3:00pm     Garcia Mendez
```

The change in shift ID represents a new shift. I want to combine all of 123456 into one row based on the first start time and the last end time of shift 123456. My second question is how could I make sure my code differentiates between Shift IDs so it doesn't combine all of the shifts together

Comment: Please update your question with a small sample of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you could do this with formulas:

I set it up like this:

[image]

Then I add the following formulas

In F2 I put the following Array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$100,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$1:$F1,$A$2:$A$100),0)),"")
```

It being an array formula, After pasting the formula in the formula bar, instead of hitting enter or tab to leave I hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter. This tells Excel it is an array formula.

Then in G2,H2,I2 I put the following formulas:

```
=IF(F2<>"",INDEX($B$2:$B$100,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($A$2:$A$100=F2)*(ROW($1:$99)),1)),"")
=IF(F2<>"",INDEX($C$2:$C$100,AGGREGATE(14,6,1/($A$2:$A$100=F2)*(ROW($1:$99)),1)),"")
=IF(F2<>"",INDEX($D$2:$D$100,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($A$2:$A$100=F2)*(ROW($1:$99)),1)),"")
```

Respectively.  These are regular formula and can be entered with just the normal way.

Then copy down.  In the following picture I copied down to the 20th row.  This way as shifts are added the formula automatically picks them up.

[image]

I know you did not ask for a formula resolution, but it is here if you want it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what do you mean by Combine rows. To check if next id  is same or not try below one.

```
For x = 1 To LR1

     If (Cells(x,2).value =   Cells(x+1,2).value ) 'To Chcek if Id is same
     Else
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I edited my post to clarify what I'm trying to do if that helps.